# Android app to read text messages

Tags: android, android-activity

How do we read text messages through an app? is it done using permissions in the manifest? Does some other approach exist?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not only is your idea malicious, but your question is also off topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.You can visit this post [How to access the SMS storage on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809874/how-to-access-the-sms-storage-on-android). In this link you can see how android has access the Sms and mms storage.