# Read SMS from Android phone connected via USB

Tags: android, sms, mms

I'm totally newbie in programming in Android. I wated to write application that reads SMS/MMS from my phone (Android 4.4) connected to my PC via USB.

Before, I have made investigation how I can do it, but nothing helped me :( Here's my investigation result and approaches how to do it.

1. Copy mmssms.db file

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/where-on-the-file-system-are-sms-messages-stored

First of all, I couln't find mentioned file on my phone.

2. GTalkSMS

[How to access the SMS storage on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809874/how-to-access-the-sms-storage-on-android)

I guess that in that case I would need to write an application and run this app on my phone. Right? I mustn't run this app on my phone. I just need to run application on my PC and read saved sms/mms from my Phone via USB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, did you do it? Please enlighten me how to read sms from android phone

Comment: i have the same requirement, please share if any have a solution